# Intance cannot access to its class attribute in the definition

Tags: python

I define a class `Task`

```
class Task:
    format_str ='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
    def __init__(self, name, start, end):
        self.name = name
        self.start = datetime.strptime(start,format_str)
        self.end = datetime.strptime(end,format_str)

    @property
    def consumed(self):
        return self.end - self.start
```

Pass arguments and create an instance:

```
task1 = Task(name='1.learn class',
            start = '2017-11-11 19:10:46.327740',
            end = '2017-11-11 20:00:18.604630')
```

When running,I get a NameError.

```
NameError: name 'format_str' is not defined
```

I learn that Class attributes are attributes which are owned by the class itself. They will be shared by all the instances of the class. [Python3 Tutorial: Class vs. Instance Attributes](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_class_and_instance_attributes.php)

`format_str ='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f` is a surely a class attribute.It should be accessed by all its instances.

What's problem with my code?

Comment: Think you need self.format_str

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Task' object has no attribute 'format_str'` it works with `Task.format_str`. confused. @raykrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the class name:

```
Task.format_str
```